# JSON newline delimited

Tags: amazon-s3, ndjson

I have a requirement whereby a third-party system will require to consume JSON files as newline delimited or [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) from an AWS S3 bucket. I am struggling to find information on how S3 deals with such format. Can I save files as ndsjon?

Thank you

Comment: Amazon S3 is just a storage system. It does not care about the format of what is _contained_ in the files. Or, are you talking about [Amazon S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/), which can perform queries on CSV/JSON files stored in S3? Or perhaps Amazon Athena, which is a Presto-like service that can query files stored in S3?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about S3 as I will be getting files in JSON format, but the consumer will require translating it onto ndjson. From what you said, I think the only thing I might need is some logic in my lambda  function to make sure that my 3rd party can consume the data in the required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, S3 supports any data to store in bucket, since it's a block storage.

From [Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) — Cloud Storage — AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/):

> **Q: What kind of data can I store in Amazon S3?**
>
> You can store virtually any kind of data in any format. Please refer to the [Amazon Web Services Licensing Agreement](https://aws.amazon.com/agreement/) for details.